# Saving multiple files in Eclipse using Ctrl+s causes "The file cannot be edited"

Tags: eclipse, file, locking, save, js-test-driver

I'm regularly an IntelliJ IDEA user, but because jsTestDriver doesn't work with IDEA, I am forced to use eclipse. I am getting a very annoying error message every time I save my javascript files with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut.

In IDEA, it just saves the files for me... and I never run into any problems ever. It is literally the most unobtrusive saving model ever, and I love it.

But with this IDE - eclipse - I have to constantly save the files manually. Anyway, I've gotten used to it, but if I am making changes to 2 or more files, when I press CTRL-S, this error message pops up 2+ times. It is so annoying.

[image: Error message]

Even worse, it's affecting my unit test results with jsTestDriver! Sometimes 0 tests runs, other times it crashes half-way... all because the files weren't saved.

Can anyone help me fix this? IDEA is not running at the same time either. Just STS/Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After googling the error message it seems this is coming from `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException`. Although a bit outdated try to see whether the solution in the comments of [this](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.com/2004/10/worst-eclipse-crash-ever.html) post solve this issue.

Comment: That guys problem is extreme different to mine. Same exception, but totally different :/

Comment: yes it's about OSGi but it comes down to org.eclipse.core which is part of eclipse. As they suggest there try deleting \.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.snap and \.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\.markers.snap, of course keeping backups before you do so.

Comment: sigh... i am fed up with eclipse. It is an awful ide. IDEA is literally so much better in hundreds of cases. I really don't understand the following behind it, because I find my productivity drops astronomically. There are just so many little things that are not even problems with IDEA, but you have to intervene and help it... or it does the wrong default that makes no sense. I can think of countless examples. With IDEA, there are no such problems. It just does the 'right' thing. Man, I wish jsTestDriver actually worked with IDEA... that's the real solution. Pitty.